# c# Mathematic and logical binary tree expression solver

Tags: c#, parsing, binary-tree

I'm looking for best practices and experience to implement (or use an existing ) a c# binary tree parser.

## What I want to do

I'm coding an app where any visitor will be able to type a custom expression to:

1. Filter a table of results
2. Do some "simple" math operations

I want to save those expressions in database to create a list of known filters and perform them later on server side in C#.

## What I found

### Client side : JSEP

[JSEP](http://jsep.from.so/) looks pretty simple and extensible if needed.
JSEP also provide a JSON which describes "simple" expressions (to perform math in service side) and more complex ones (to filter data in server side).

[image: math expression]

[image: complex expression]

### Server side

I didn't find any C# package related to JSEP, but some nice tutorials like this one [C# parser tutorial](https://www.giorgi.dev/net-framework/building-expression-evaluator-with-expression-trees-in-csharp-table-of-contents/) or existing advanced C# parser like this one [Dynamic Linq Query Builder](https://github.com/castle-it/dynamic-linq-query-builder) used for [jQuery Query Builder](https://querybuilder.js.org/).

## What I'm looking for

It's the first time I have to do this kind of dev. Based on my research this subject is not really common...
So before to start I would like to know if I'm missing something? or if you have any advice?